# Multuple return values in one spec for a spy

Tags: angular, jasmine

In my spec I am spying on a mockService like this

```
  spyOn(mockService, 'method').and.returnValue(
      value1
  );
```

than in the same spec, I would like to do

```
  spyOn(mockService, 'method').and.returnValue(
      value2
  );
```

but it tells me that `mockService.method` has already been spied upon.
How can I make the existing spy return a new value ?

If I do `mockService.method.and.returnValue(value2)` I get a type error. I could do `mockService as Spy` but is there a more straighforward way of returnin a new value  for a spy ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd strongly recommend trying to write your specs such that you separate the need for the two mocks into 2 separate `it` blocks, you can probably get away with just capturing the method being mocked on your mockService and then just reassigning it before doing the second mock.

Eg.

```
let originalMethod = mockService.method;
spyOn(mockService, 'method').and....

// later,
mockService.method = originalMethod;
spyOn(mockService, 'method).and ......
```